# Include leading zeros in excel export file

Tags: c#, excel, leading-zero

I have a c# windows application that lets a user to export data from a datagridview to an excel file.

My problem is that exported file does not include leading zeros in the cells. So "00001" is displayed as "1".

I tried putting single quote (') before the value to be written on the file but the quote is also displayed. '00001

Is there a way that the single quote not be displayed and it only displays 00001?

Here's the code that I used in writing to the file.

```
  private void btn_Export_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
        sfd.Filter = "Excel Documents (*.xls)|*.xls";
        if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            // ToCsV(dataGridView1, @"c:\temp\export.xls");   ???????
            ToCsV(dgv_SLAccounts, sfd.FileName);
            MessageBox.Show("Successfully Created " + sfd.FileName);
        }  
    }

     private void ToCsV(DataGridView dGV, string filename)
    {
        string stOutput = "";
        // Export titles:
        string sHeaders = "";

        for (int j = 0; j < dGV.Columns.Count; j++)
            sHeaders = sHeaders.ToString() + Convert.ToString(dGV.Columns[j].HeaderText) + "\t";
        stOutput += sHeaders + "\n";
        // Export data.
        for (int i = 0; i < dGV.RowCount - 1; i++)
        {
            string stLine = "";
            for (int j = 0; j < dGV.Rows[i].Cells.Count; j++)
                stLine = stLine.ToString() +"'"+ Convert.ToString(dGV.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value) + "\t";
            stOutput += stLine + "\n";  
        }
        Encoding utf16 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1254);
        byte[] output = utf16.GetBytes(stOutput);
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create);
        BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);
        bw.Write(output, 0, output.Length); //write the encoded file
        bw.Flush();
        bw.Close();
        fs.Close();
    }
```

Comment: I don't use Excel for csv anymore. Even though zeros are there, it won't show. You may open it in notepad or try some other 3rd party wares

Answer (score 1):

Add \t before your string. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Excel will not display leading zeroes in CSV files. Your only option is to write the file in XLS or XLSX format, and then format the range containing the leading-zero cells as text.

Answer (score 0):

Leading zeroes can indeed be preserved in CSV files when using Excel at least. You were also pretty close to the working solution in trying to use the single quote in front of the number.

However, the solution is to write the number with leading zeroes as a function:

```
="00001"
```

This way, Excel will interpret the value as a string and will not strip out the leading zeroes.

Try this code (adapted from your original):

```
stLine = stLine.ToString() +"=\""+ Convert.ToString(dGV.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value) + "\"\t";
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 int i=1;        
 Console.WriteLine(i.ToString().PadLeft(5,'0'));
```

Comment: stLine = stLine.ToString() +"'"+ Convert.ToString(dGV.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value).PadLeft(5,'0') + "\t";

Still displaying "1" instead of "000001"

Comment: The data "000001" is from the database (being displayed on a data grid) and I want it to be exported in the excel file in the same format. But the excel file only displays "1" instead of "000001". The leading zeros were stripped out from the original value. Please Help.. :(

Comment: JasonX this is Excel Problem try changing the excel auto convert option else add dummy row with a string say"Samp"

Answer (score -2):

Use a format string when writing out your integer like so:

```
int i = 1; 
Console.WriteLine(i.ToString("00000"));
```

More info on custom numeric format strings here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)